# ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest in Controller Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

When running legacy controller tests like this one:

```
    get :edit, id: object.id, format: :js
```

My tests began failing in Rails 4.1 with the following error:

```
ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest: Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

For Rails 5+

```
get :edit, params: { id: object.id }, xhr: true
```

Comment: Hi, which file should this code go in? `routes.rb`?

Comment: No this goes in your test files whenever you are calling a javascript request (like AJAX) in your tests.

Comment: Ah, I see. My ICOR was in production, rather than in tests.

Answer (score 40):

Older versions of Rails accepted this, but the solution was to use the `xhr` method as follows:

```
  xhr :get, :edit, id: object.id
```

Comment: This syntax has changed to `get edit_url(object), xhr: true` in Rails 5.